# how to push data from safari into application document directory

Tags: iphone, safari

I want to open safari browser from where I can choose any image/text and directly save it to application directory.
What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible, App are sandboxed and can't directly access each others data.

There for there is no option to save data saving option in safari. All you can do is tell iOS that your app can handle some file extension. 
This will then allow safarie, mail or any other app if the is an app which can open a file type.

Comment: How can I tell iOS to behave like this.Can you please put some highlight on this.

Comment: Well you should really start by reading the Apple Documentation on iOS: [The iOS Environment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)